# making my variable acceptable for my print statement

Tags: java, jgrasp

I am at the end of my program and hit a snag. I know that without fail my program inputs a numbers file and will find the lowest value. my snag is how to write out my highest value variable so that it will run through my while loop and assign a value for my print line statement.....here is my program

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class LargenSmalltest
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{

    //Open the file
    File file = new File("Numbers.txt");
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);


    String filename;                                 
    double lowest = inputFile.nextDouble();  //lowest first number in list
    double highest = lowest;

    //Read all the values in Numbers file 
    while (inputFile.hasNext())
    {
        //Read second value from file
        double number = inputFile.nextDouble();

        //Read the numbers in the file and compare each value to find lowest value
        if (number < lowest) 
            //The lowest number in the list has now been stored as lowest
            lowest = number;
    }

    //Reread all the values in Numbers file 
    while (inputFile.hasNext())
    {
        //number equals the second value in your list
        double number = inputFile.nextDouble();

        if (number > highest)   
            highest = number;
    }

    //Close file
    inputFile.close();

    //Print out the lowest value in the list
    System.out.println("The lowest number in your file called, " +
      "Numbers.txt is "   +lowest+ ".");

    System.out.println("The highest number in your file is, " +highest+ ".");
}
```

}

Comment: What behavior do you expect? What behavior are you seeing? Also, you should really consider indenting your code.

Answer (score 2):

Agreed with @rgettman. Also what's happening is that your scanner is reading the whole file but it can't be started over or reversed. If you were going to go through a file again you would need to create a new scanner.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to have that second `while` loop.  With your two loops, you use up all the values in the first loop, and there are none left for the second loop.

You can perform your lowest and highest tests on the same `number` in one loop:

```
while (inputFile.hasNext())
{
   // Read second value from file
   double number = inputFile.nextDouble();

   // Read the numbers in the file and compare each value to find lowest value
   if (number < lowest) 
      //The lowest number in the list has now been stored as lowest
      lowest = number;

   // Find the highest value.
   if (number > highest)
      highest = number;
}
```